# Adding a span to a tab in the header template

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

In order to make my site a bit more user friendly. I would like to add an icon on to a tab via a span from codebehind. Just to let users know that the tab isn't empty.

Currently I have a label with the text Documents.

```
<act1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer" runat="server" Width="100%" Visible="true" CssClass="MyTabStyle" ActiveTabIndex="0" OnPreRender="TabContainer_PreRender" >
<act1:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tbDocuments" HeaderText="Documents" TabIndex="3"  >

<HeaderTemplate>
    <div class="divTab">
        <asp:Label ID="lbDocuments" runat="server" Text="Documents"></asp:Label>
    </div>                                                                                        
</HeaderTemplate>
```

How can I add

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
```

after the asp label in the header template via codebehind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add a Literal to the HeaderTemplate

```
<div class="divTab">
    <asp:Label ID="lbDocuments" runat="server" Text="Documents"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```

Then use FindControl to locate the Literal and add the icon.

```
Literal lit = tbDocuments.FindControl("Literal1") as Literal;
lit.Text = "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-search\"></span>";
```

You may need to tweak the FindControl a little to get it working with `act1` Controls. I don't have those and cannot test it exactly. You could also have to locate `TabContainer` first.

Comment: This is perfect. In my case I could just access the control directly just by doing this. lDocuments.Text = "<span class=\"fa fa-file\"></span>";  Thanks a ton.